# Word meaning "having the power to both create and destroy something"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word, noun or adjective, that conveys the meaning "having the power to both create and destroy" something specific. For example:

> The magician **seemingly** had < *insert word here* > over rabbits, able to pull them from thin air, and equally return them to nothingness

Or

> The network administrator can both create and delete user accounts, they have < *insert word here* > over/on/with user accounts.

Some words that I've considered but don't quite fit are

- sovereignty (too specific to politics)
- potency (not quite right)
- omnipotence (implies non specific power)

To clear  some things up in response to comments.

- the creation/destruction need not be physical.
- there's no wizardry involved. Regarding the magician, think stage performer not wizard
- the word should not be limited to power over a specific thing, e.g. sovereignty grants per to create and repeal laws, but not the power to create and destroy rabbits
- the word should be modifiable in combination with a subject to indicate a single thing or concept to which the power applies
- the word should not be too general, such as omnipotence meaning power over everything

Comment: This is quite far from the mark, but *refiability* (from [*reify*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reify)) may be a slight nudge in the right direction. The ability to construct is explicit; to destroy, implicit.

Comment: For the wizzard, consider "omnipotence" or "overwhelming or full power". For the network administrator, you may use "full authority".

Comment: *full power*, *total control*, would fit.

Comment: In the real, physical world, it is impossible to create or destroy matter. The laws in question are some of the most fundamental humanity currently knows of: the conversation of mass (or, equivalently and more commonly used, the conservation of energy). So the wizard's magic must be precisely in breaking or subverting these laws.  So you could riff on the idea of your sorcerers being "conservity-breaking" or "non-conservative", etc. Or, you could invoke Noether's theorem relating conservation laws to symmetries, and say your magi are "time variant" (vs "time invariance").

Comment: I brought you into this world, I can take you out of it.

Comment: @lawrence close enough for me, make it an answer and I would accept, failling a better one.

Comment: @dan I'm not necessarily looking at physical creation. A programmer could create an artificial intelligence, and destroy it by pulling the plug, but not control it. None of this requires the villain of any physical laws.

Comment: @sirlark Posted as requested :) .

Comment: For programmers, _crud_. :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [invited](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/322795/word-meaning-having-the-power-to-both-create-and-destroy-something?noredirect=1#comment734523_322795):

Consider *reifiability* (from *reify*) as a nudge in the right direction:

> **Reify** *verb*
>   Make (something abstract) more concrete or real
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reify)

The ability to construct is explicit in the term, and the ability to destroy is implicit.

Comment: Has this word ever been seen in a dictionary or in the wild?

Comment: @Greybeard. Yes, my ODO link is an instance of this "seen in a dictionary" (ODO has been replaced by dictionary.com since I posted my answer). It's also used "in the wild" quite a bit in some branches of computing. See, for example, page 299 of the volume ["Interactive Theorem Proving"](https://www.google.com.au/books/edition/Interactive_Theorem_Proving/I-tiDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22reify%22&pg=PA299&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: That's reify, which is fine: it's "reifiability" that worries me.

Comment: @Greybeard English is a productive language. Adding -able turns the verb into an adjective (see [this wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reifiable#:~:text=Capable%20of%20being%20reified.)), and adding -ability turns the verb into a noun.

Answer (score 3):

There is a legal sense of absolute ownership in [dominion](//legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/dominion) that might fit.

*"Perfect control in right of ownership. The word implies both title and possession and appears to require a complete retention of control over disposition. Title to an article of property, which arises from the power of disposition and the right of claiming it..."*

There is also an idiomatic use:  [gain dominion over](//idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Dominion) someone or something:  *to achieve total authority over someone or something.*

Comment: Nice, but also implies more control than I intend

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use omnipotent

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/omnipotent

Comment: Thanks, I considered that, and have updated the question accordingly. I'm looking for something without the connotation of power over everything. Also, the ability to create and/or destroy does not imply the ability to control, which omnipotence does

Comment: Please explain why you feel this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want a word for "power" that applies to both the ability to *materialize/ manifest/ conjure/ generate/ summon/ annihilate* or *reify/ concretize* through a [performative utterance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performative_utterance), or **prestidigitation**, as well as the word for something that is in your **purview**.

Based on your follow-up comments, it seems like you want a word that isn't too strong (dominion/sovereignty are too strong to use), so I think part of the challenge is to find a word that's not too strong for **purview** but strong enough for **prestidigitation**. To resolve this, I'm thinking of finding a word that works for the latter "purview example", that can be used metaphorically in the "prestidigitation example". (Or just use "power"! Or just use two words for each situation! Based on your clarification, I'm still not quite sure what's wrong with "power"?) You liked "reify" but that doesn't work for both examples, does it?

Words like "***command, authority, governance, purview***" come to mind. However, I think the word that comes closest to working for both examples is "**prerogative**". [Pregoative can refer](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/prerogative) to a "power or immunity" that is unique to the situation you deploy the word. In other words:

> **`Prerogative`**
>
> "a right, privilege, [power,] etc. unique to a specific person or persons of a particular category"

The "power" sense of prerogative can be specific to a governance/polity, but can also be [metaphorical](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/prerogative), as in "it's your prerogative to [do something]".

I think that captures all of your stipulations: not necessarily physical power, works for magician example, not limited to one thing (such as state power), not overly general either (eg, omnipotence). The word is also "modifiable in combination with a subject to indicate a single thing or concept to which the power applies", for example, "royal prerogatives" or perhaps "**existential prerogatives**" ([example](https://cio.economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/corporate-news/hyperautomation-an-existential-prerogative-for-organizations/89816390?redirect=1)) when referring to being about to magically being able to bring/remove something from existence. Prerogative also works for the more quotidian example of a network administrator.

refs:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performative_utterance
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/prerogative https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/prerogative
https://cio.economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/corporate-news/hyperautomation-an-existential-prerogative-for-organizations/89816390?redirect=1

Answer (score -1):

Reimancy- The overarching magic school of conjuration- the ability to bring something into existance from seemingly nothing, and abjuration- the ability to make something become nothing.  This looks like its creating or destroying a thing, but its merely moving it somewhere else in the multiverse.

Comment: -1: this answer is completely incorrect. *Reimancy* doesn't exist in English, it's an invented word used by a fantasy roleplaying site. *Abjuration* is the renunciation of something by oath: your definition is an invention.

Answer (score -1):

Metamorphosis - the ability to change form (destroy the old and create the new), and both butterflies and magicians do it... Essentially, the technical term for what you describe is "change".

Comment: This doesn't work for either example given in the question.

Answer (score -3):

> The magician seemingly had ***meddle*** over rabbits, able to pull
>   them from thin air, and equally return them to nothingness.

Or

> The network administrator can both create and delete user accounts,
>   they have ***meddled*** over/on/with user accounts.

I think the word 'meddle' is what you're looking for simply because it implies an unfinished state of being, somewhere between 'creation' and 'destruction'.

Comment: I've never seen "meddled" as anything but the past tense or past participle of meddle. Is it possible you're thinking of another word?

Comment: *meddle* means "interfere in something that is not one's concern", which is not the meaning the OP is looking for. Also, it's a *verb* - it's incorrect to say "had meddle over" (using it as a noun).